# Include a folder from the included Jar file - Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, properties, build, dependencies

I have project called `ProjectA` that has a jar called `JarA` as dependency.

Now JarA has several folders with the property files. `ProjectA` needs one of the folders (lets called it `FolderA`) from `JarA`.

`JarA` is included in the `ProjectA` war file. How do I include `FolderA` from `JarA` to the `ProjectA`'s build path?

`ProjectA`'s war file structure looks like this:

```
   ...
   WEB-INF
          lib
             JarA.jar
                     FolderA
                     FolderB
                     ....
                     com
                        company
                               blah
```

I use Gradle. So I need a way to include `FolderA`.

Comment: I'm not certain you can partially include a Jar's contents. You could however explode the jar, repack only what you need and then include that partial jar.

Comment: @RaGe I need entire `JarA.jar`. But also include `FolderA` or Files from `FolderA` to be available to `ProjectA `. Not that i want to remove `JarA` dependency.

Comment: Maybe a shadow jar is what you need? You might want to take a look at that (it also shadows resources)